# ARM v7: SIMD lookup table for 32-bit floats

Tags: arm, intrinsics, neon

I have a vector of float32 numbers. For each element I have to find cos,sin

I want to use a lookup table instead of the default library.
Is there an ARM intrinsic code I can use for this purpose ?

Comment: Is there some limited range to your floats, or do you want tables of 2^32 entries (which would take 16 GiB of RAM, and thus can't fit in a 32-bit machine).  Normally you'd only use a lookup table to get an initial guess for some kind of refinement, or as a very coarse approximation.

Comment: And BTW, no, ARM doesn't have SIMD gather loads for parallel indexing of an arbitrary array in memory of 32 or 64-bit elements.  At least not with NEON; I forget if SVE added that.

Comment: SVE2 has gather loads

Comment: It depends on how much precision is good enough for your purpose. The standard library is overly precise at the cost of performance. If you can live with less, there are tons of ways dealing with sin/cos. Determine first how much precision you need.

Answer (score 6):

Arm v7 has `uint8x8_t vtbl4_u8(uint8x8x4_t tbl, uint8x8_t idx)` to extract 8 values in parallel from a table of size 32. Other table sizes are 8,16 and 24 entries; Also a `uint8x8_t vtbxN_u8(uint8x8_t result, uint8x8xN_t tbl, uin8x8_t idx)` variant is available, which does not clear a lane if the corresponding idx is out of range. The vtbx can be thus used to extend the table size.

These instructions/intrinsics can be used e.g. for piecewise polynomial approximation to get the coefficients at each range. However I would not expect such a solution to be efficient for floats, as one would need 3 or 4 tables for linear interpolation and 6 to 8 tables for piecewise quadratic interpolation - each table would provide just one byte of the 4-byte float32_t coefficient.

In contrast, adding few more entries to Taylor or McLaurin expansion is vastly more efficient in terms of memory, instruction count and latency.

Comment: Why 3 (or fewer) tables? One can at least try to shift the arguments / output of the polynomials to a range where the top byte i.e. the exponent of the floating point encoding is constant over all the outputs or arguments. Also quantizing the coefficients and relaxing on accuracy would help in not tabulating the least significant byte.

Comment: Hi Aki. Thank you very much for your reply. You wrote: "adding few more entries to Taylor ...". Do you mean that I should rewrite sin/cos with taylor series ?

Comment: Yes, taylor series works exceptionally well for sin/cos after range reduction to +-pi/2 or +-pi/4.

Comment: I tried "my" sin, cos each calculated with 3 taylor series elements. The performance was ~20 times slower than sin,cos from gcc.  My C code contains scalar arithmetic only.

Comment: I need an accuracy of 1E-5. How can I know how many values I need ?

Comment: It's enough to evaluate the Taylor polynomials at the furthest value `(x-a)`, here `a=0` to find out if the accuracy is enough; thus just add up terms. More optimal solutions however use Chebysev polynomials, which are computed to minimise the overall error.